# How to make jQuery UI sortable, draggable and droppable work at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Given the below code, how can I:

1. Make the `li` sortable.
2. How can the `li` be dragged into to the `ul.droppable` and remain sortable within it?
3. How can the `li` dragged into the `ul.droppable` be dragged out of the `ul.droppable` and return to under directly `ul.sortable`?

```html
<ul class="sortable">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>
        <ul class="droppable" style="border:1px dashed #000;min-height:200px;">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>       
</ul>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.sortable').sortable({});

    $('.droppable').droppable({
        hoverClass: '<div style="border: 1px dashed red; height: 20px; width: 100%;"></div>',
        drop: function (e, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
        }
    });     

    $('.sortable li').draggable({
        helper: function(event, ui) {
            return '<div style="border: 1px dashed blue; height: 20px; width: 100%;"></div>';
        } 
    });         
});
```

I hope that's clear to you, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle please ?

Comment: Sure https://jsfiddle.net/dontsome/L3qydh2o/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the included `jQuery UI` library.

```
added external resource...
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3qydh2o/1/)

BTW: Just open the browser debugging console to see the errors.

HTML:

```
<ul id="droppable-2">
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
    <li>Test 7</li>
    <li>Test 8</li>
    <li>Test 9</li>     
</ul>

<ul id="droppable" style="border:1px dashed #000;min-height:200px;">
</ul>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var droppableObj = {
        hoverClass: '<div style="border:1px dashed red;height:20px;width:100%;"></div>',
        drop: function (e, ui) {
            var $item = $(ui.draggable);
            $(this).append($item);
        }
    };

    $('#droppable').droppable(droppableObj);    
    $('#droppable-2').droppable(droppableObj);

    $('#droppable-2 li').draggable({
        helper: function(event, ui) {
            return '<div style="border:1px dashed blue;height:20px;width:100%;"></div>';
        } 
    }); 
});
```

[Here is the new version.](https://jsfiddle.net/L3qydh2o/3/)

Comment: No it can be dragged into the ul.droppable, but can't be dragged out

Comment: The new version is working but sorry in my actual project everything is within the ul.droppable so there is only one ul

Comment: Why you cannot change it?